# Fetching wrong Employee count corresponding to office location in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation, testng

I am fetching Employee count according to locating using Map
Highlighted No of employees count is mismatch in Image
like If i search in Web table Tokyo there count is 5 but here getting 6
for Edingburg, singapore , syndney count is correct.

Unable to find what is getting wrong in code
can anyone explain ?

[image]

```
public class EmployeeMapping extends PredefinedActions {
WebDriver driver;
WebDriverWait wait;
JavascriptExecutor js;

@BeforeTest
void setUp() {
    driver = start("https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/excel");
}
//Clicking on each number 1,2
@Test(priority = 1)
void officeAndNumberMapping1() {
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//td[text()='Ashton']")));
    WebElement scrollElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='Ashton']"));

    js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", scrollElement);
    Map<String, Integer> officeNumberMap = new HashMap<>();

    int totalTableRowsize = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span/a[@tabindex='0']")).size();

    for (int outerIndex = 1; outerIndex <= totalTableRowsize; outerIndex++) {
        int rowSize = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[@role='row']//td[5]")).size();
        for (int index = 1; index <= rowSize; index++) {            
            String officeLocation = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody//tr[" + index + "]//td[5]")).getText();
            if (officeNumberMap.containsKey(officeLocation)) {
                officeNumberMap.put(officeLocation, officeNumberMap.get(officeLocation) + 1);
            } else {
                officeNumberMap.put(officeLocation, 1);
            }
        }           
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='example_paginate']/span/a["+outerIndex+"]")).click();   
    }
    System.out.println(officeNumberMap);
}}
```

**Link:** [AutoFill and KeyTable together](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/excel.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.get().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='example_paginate']/span/a["+outerIndex+"]")).click();
```

1. Here when the page-load you are in index tab one already
2. After the first iteration, you are again clicking the same tab as
   outerIndex is still 1
3. so it counts page one content twice

**So for fix, just keep the click action at the start than end of totalTableRowsize loop:**

```
public class EmployeeMapping extends PredefinedActions {
  WebDriver driver;
  WebDriverWait wait;
  JavascriptExecutor js;

  @BeforeTest
  void setUp() {
    driver = start("https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/excel");
  }
  //Clicking on each number 1,2
  @Test(priority = 1)
  void officeAndNumberMapping1() {
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//td[text()='Ashton']")));
    WebElement scrollElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='Ashton']"));

    js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", scrollElement);
    Map < String,
    Integer > officeNumberMap = new HashMap < >();

    int totalTableRowsize = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span/a[@tabindex='0']")).size();

    for (int outerIndex = 1; outerIndex <= totalTableRowsize; outerIndex++) {
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='example_paginate']/span/a[" + outerIndex + "]")).click();
      int rowSize = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[@role='row']//td[5]")).size();
      for (int index = 1; index <= rowSize; index++) {
        String officeLocation = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody//tr[" + index + "]//td[5]")).getText();
        if (officeNumberMap.containsKey(officeLocation)) {
          officeNumberMap.put(officeLocation, officeNumberMap.get(officeLocation) + 1);
        } else {
          officeNumberMap.put(officeLocation, 1);
        }
      }

    }
    System.out.println(officeNumberMap);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @PDHide for help. 
 it worked.